# How to document operations on a database?

Tags: databases, methodology

I am working on a scientific article, where I am going to work with a large SQL based database. This work consist of everything from washing data, creating sub-databases etc. How can I document this work, in a scientific matter - so I know what has been done with the data?

Answer (score 2):

You could add all SQL statements to GitHub and then use the Commit Descriptions. Depending on how extensive this is you can also write a manual change log. Or you simply excessively comment inside your sql statements. Then I would recommend to also add some kind of timestamp.

If you are familiar with jupyter and using python and sql together you can also use this.